# Excel 2013 side-by-side sheet view

Tags: microsoft-excel, window, microsoft-office-2013

In Excel 2013, if I want to view different sheets from the same workbook side-by-side I first have to click View->New window otherwise the side-by-side option is greyed out.

After I click both New window and then side-by-side both windows get maximized such that they fill the whole screen. Resizing to previous size (e.g. original workbook/sheet size) isn't practical to say the least...

Is there any way to disable this window maximize which happens by default?

Comment: See if this works: After adding the new window, click **Arrange All** on the View tab and then choose **Vertical** and enable the **Windows of active workbook** checkbox. After doing this, does the View Side by Side feature work as you desire?

Comment: No, it still maximizes

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: Windows 10 PRO x64,
note: I use two screens (4K), if it makes a difference?